Cursed VS accursed
What is the difference between the term cursed and accursed? I have read that accursed sounds more archaic, but I wonder if there is any slight difference in meaning.
I was surprised to learn of the existence of the word accursed when reading the alternative naming of the Albanian Alps, Accursed mountains. Fascinating, so I started wondering about other common usages of this word, and if it has any difference with cursed.

Pretty much as you think. There are lots of English words that have an intensive prefix but mean basically the same as without the prefix. Sometimes there are small differences like solve v resolve. Sometimes one becomes more common than the other (maze (verb) v amaze). Sometimes there's not much difference - accursed might be old-fashioned but so now is cursed.

accursed is literary in today's speech.

There is a slight difference, in that 'accursed' needs no qualification, but 'cursed' does.
Being 'accursed' speaks for itself: you're in big trouble; never mind what trouble.
Being 'cursed' more likely means 'cursed to…' which is to say you are condemned to do, or not to do, something specific.
'Midas was accursed…' tells us merely that he suffered.
'Midas was cursed to turn to gold all he touched…' tells us the nature of the curse.
'The Wandering Jew was accursed…' means what?
'The Wandering Jew was cursed to walk the Earth forever' tells us the nature of the curse.

You can also say "cursed by a witch" but not "accursed by a wiitch". "accursed" has essentially become an adjective, while "cursed" is a past participle.

For me something or someone being 'cursed' means having one or more specific, formal curses pronounced on it or them. 'Accursed', however carries an implication of being generally feared or abhorred and, possibly, being cursed informally (for example "these damn mountains will be the death of us") but without a formal curse of any sort being expressed. I have no evidence that this is generally true hence my presentation of it as a comment rather than an answer.

If people are only comfortable posting their answer in comments, perhaps this website is accursed... Or cursed? What would be the best word here? :)

See: Accursed vs Cursed: Deciding Between Similar Terms https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/accursed-vs-cursed

It is true that dictionary definitions don't always clarify such differences. Take for example Collins:

If a person is accursed, they have been cursed. [literary]

However, ambiguous as it may seem, this short definition already points out two differences:

As @Barmar wrote in a comment, accursed is often used as an adjective (and has survived in such names as The Accursed Mountains, that you mention, or The Accursed Lake, The Accursed City, etc.). Whereas cursed is used as the past participle of the verb to curse (See also this Ngram).

Collins labels accursed as literary, even old fashioned. So if you use it, you show your intention to evoke a past epoch or use a more dramatic register of language.


Also, the same dictionary indicates a usage of accursed to describe things that deserve to be cursed:

Some people use accursed to describe something which they are very annoyed about.

And we need something a little better than this accursed nonsense about the survival of the fittest.


Note that Collins specifies that this meaning is used prenominally:

(prenominal) 
hateful; detestable; execrable

But when you describe something as cursed, it means:

experiencing problems and unhappiness (HAVING BAD LUCK)

I think my car is cursed - it never starts when I need it. (Cambridge)


